# Can't upload file to sftp server with Paramiko Python

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I want to upload a file to a SFTP server using Paramiko, but I don't seem to get it right.
I thought I got the respective error cause of the file path '/' witch is the root on the server but I didn't get anywhare.
I keep getting this error:

```
  File "c:\python\whitelistBot\whitelistBot.py", line 63, in on_message
    sftp_client.put('C:/python/whitelistBot/whitelist1.json', '/')
  File "C:\python\whitelistBot\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 759, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "C:\python\whitelistBot\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 714, in putfo
    with self.file(remotepath, "wb") as fr:
  File "C:\python\whitelistBot\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 372, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "C:\python\whitelistBot\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 813, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "C:\python\whitelistBot\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 865, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "C:\python\whitelistBot\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 898, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)
OSError: Operation Unsupported
```

The code I'm running:

```py
import paramiko


FTP_HOST = "********"
FTP_USER = "********"
FTP_PASS = "********"
FTP_PORT = ****

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname= FTP_HOST, username=FTP_USER, password=FTP_PASS, port=FTP_PORT)
sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()

sftp_client.put('C:/python/whitelistBot/whitelist1.json', '/')

sftp_client.close()
ssh_client.close()
```

EDIT: I changed the directory where to put the file  to "/home/container" cause that's what they told me in the site but except for the fact that I don't get that error message, the file does not appear on the server

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to specify the name of the file '/whitelist1.json' like so:

```py
sftp_client.put('C:/python/whitelistBot/whitelist1.json', '/whitelist1.json') # don't know why but yeah
```